# Change to a directory and get current directory using FTPFileTransfer

Tags: 7

1) Suppose I am in directory "/home/stream". Which class should I use in FTPFileTransfer to get the directory "/home/stream".

suppose in php to get the current directory we use "ftp_pwd"

How to know the **current directory** using **FTPFileTransfer**.

2)  In PHP we use "ftp_chdir" to change to a directory.

Suppose if my current directory is "/home/stream" , how to **change to directory** "/home/stream/public_html" using **FTPFileTransfer**.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I get what yo're asking, but would it perhaps be possible to expand slightly just so people can be sure?  Thanks :)

Comment: @Chapabu: Edited by question.